# ffmpeg with a python wrapper-- need help avoiding multiple passes on a file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I would like some help refactoring this code to reduce the amount of passes ffmpeg must make on the file.  I figure creating a single compounded ffmpeg command would do the trick, but I am kind of lost.

```
def processVideo(videoFile, venueWatermarkFile, companyWatermarkFile, mp3File=None, m4vFile=None, cropH, cropW, resizeH, resizeW):
    if mp3File != "" :
        subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i ' + videoFile + ' -i ' + audio + ' -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:ih*480/iw, crop=480:480, loop=loop=3:size=210, trim=duration=15[video]" -shortest -map "[video]" -map "1:a?" -c:a aac new1.mp4', shell=True)
    else :
        subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i ' + videoFile + ' -i ' + audio + ' -vf "scale=480:ih*480/iw, crop=480:480" new1.mp4', shell=True)

    if m4vFile != "":   
        subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i ' + videoFile + ' -i ' + m4v + ' -filter_complex " [0:v] scale=480:ih*480/iw, crop=480:480 [bg]; [1:v] chromakey=00FF00:similarity=0.2:blend=0.3 [fg]; [bg][fg] overlay=shortest=1 [v] " -map "[v]" -map "0:a?" -f mp4 new1.mp4', shell=True)

    subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i new1.mp4 -i ' + venueWatermarkFile + ' -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy new2.mp4', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i new2.mp4 -i ' + companyWatermarkFile + ' -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy new.mp4', shell=True)

    subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i new.mp4 new.gif -hide_banner', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('ffmpeg -y -i new.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.000 -vframes 1 new.jpg', shell=True)

    os.remove("new1.mp4")
    os.remove("new2.mp4")


processVideo("video-standard.mp4", "venue-standard.png", "company-standard.png", "clip.mp3", "animation.m4v")
```

Comment: This question is mainly related to usage of ffmpeg, not to programming

Comment: I rephrased my title. =)

Comment: What is `audio`? Isn't your audio src `mp3file`? Also, your current code appears to be overwriting new1.mp4 if m4vfile is defined but you're already generating new1.mp4 in the if-else block above.